# Find the area enclosed by the projection of a curve in the coordinate planes of a field

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, area

Given $\vec f(x,y,z)=\left(ye^{xy},\:xe^{xy},\:z+y\right)$ find, through a double integral, the area enclosed by the projection in the $xz$-plane of $C:\vec\gamma(t)=\left(2\cos{(t)},\:2\cos{(t)}+3\sin{(t)},\:-3\sin{(t)}\right),\;t\in[0,2\pi]$.

---

I know I have to calculate

$$\iint\limits_{P_{xz}(C)}{\text{something}}\:\text dx\text dz$$ but I can not go further except that I did

$$C:\begin{cases}x&=2\cos{(t)}\\y&=2\cos{(t)}+3\sin{(t)}\\z&=-3\sin{(t)}\end{cases}\quad\equiv\quad \begin{cases}x&=2\cos{(t)}\\y&=x-z\\z&=-3\sin{(t)}.\end{cases}$$

How should I finish? Should I clarify that the field is $\mathcal C^1(D)$?

Thank you!

Comment: Start by working out the projection of $\gamma$. That should be pretty easy.

Comment: I don'k know how to continue from $$\begin{cases}x&=2\cos{(t)}\\y&=x-z\\z&=-3\sin{(t)}\end{cases}$$ `:(`.

Comment: What are the coordinates of an arbitrary point on the $x$-$z$ plane?

Comment: Why are we given $\vec{f}$ here ?

Comment: Thank you all. I have already solved the problem. The vector field should be removed from the statement.